# Cannot access symbols in treesit.c when building and running feature/tree-sitter

Tags: build

I'm trying out the feature branch `feature/tree-sitter` available on remote https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs.git.

Build and startup all works fine. However, the functions defined in the Emacs source module `treesit.c` are not available. For instance the function `treesit-language-available-p` described in the documentation is not available.

Currently

```
(require 'treesit nil t)
```

evaluates to `t` but

```
(when (require 'treesit nil t)
  (fboundp 'treesit-language-available-p))
```

to `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I had forgotten to pass `--with-tree-sitter` to `./configure`.

On Ubuntu 22.04 this has the prerequisite

`apt install libtree-sitter-dev`

.